# SQL: conditional SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use the following SQL query to receive all entries that are older than `payment_target` days.

```
 SELECT * from orders WHERE(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM age(CURRENT_DATE,
 date_trunc('day', orders.created_at))) - orders.payment_target*86400 >= 0)
```

However, I want to modify this query in a way that `orders.invcoice_sent_at` is used as the calculation basis if it is not null. Otherwise, `orders.created_at' should be used.

I tried it with the following query but I guess it is more pseudo code than valid SQL. I don't know how I can set the attribute to be used in the statement block.

```
 SELECT  * from orders where (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM age(CURRENT_DATE,
     date_trunc('day', IF orders.invoice_sent_at IS NOT NULL
 BEGIN orders.invoice_sent_at END
 ELSE 
 BEGIN orders.created_at END ))) - orders.payment_target*86400 >= 0)
```

Comment: Do you want to use standard SQL (unlike `EPOCH`) or would you like something vendor specific?

Comment: It has to work with PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `if` you can use `coalesce` which will work on every database supporting ANSI SQL:

```
 coalesce( orders.invoice_sent_at,  orders.created_at) - orders.payment_target*86400 >= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use a declared variable.
this will also make your code more readable. something along the lines of:

DECLARE @DUEDATE DATETIME
SET  @DUEDATE = ISNULL(("GET THE VALUE FROM orders.invoice_sent_at"),("GET THE VALUE FROM orders.created_at"))

use  @DUEDATE in your select.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9306f/1/0)

```
SELECT  *
from orders
where CURRENT_DATE - PaymentTarget > coalesce( InvoiceSent, Created );
```